# How to add text to the end of every url in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, html, text-editing, code

I have a big text file that contains urls that all begin with the same domain name but vary in the rest of the url. Is there any way to search for the line beginning with `http://test.domain` and insert text at the end of the url? I just need to add some text to the end of each url.

The urls are contained on seperate lines and are not clashing with anything so a simple method of finding the `http://test.domain` at the start of the line and inserting text at the end of the line will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with regexp.

[image: regex]

The result will be:

```
http://test.domain.com.yourText
http://test.domain.it.yourText
http://test.domain.gg.yourText
http://test.domain.wp.yourText
http://test.domain.foo.yourText
```

regexp: `(http:\/\/test\.domain.*)`

I helped myself with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674989/10307457.

First, you have to create a regexp - for testing regular expressions, you can use this website: [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/).

[image: regex testing]

Second, put it inside (brackets) - you need this for the next step to work properly.

Inside the "replace with" bar, you will be caling all the strings that you found in the previous step with `\1`, number 1 being the first (bracket) - and also the only one in our example.

Fourth, just add whatever you want to `\1`. In my example, I added `.yourText`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tested this and it works but it works on every line instead of just the lines with the links, there are also lines in the doc that do not contain links, it doesn't seem to successfully find the opening part of the url when i click find next, it just finds the next line. I'll keep playing around with it, thanks anyway!

Comment: I see - it matches every line in notepad++ for me as well. It works fine on the online regex test though - check the link for online regex test (I updated it)

Comment: Got it! , i used (test\.domain/.+) and replaced with \1.text and it works, thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the problem in my solution were the sqare brackets

Comment: Alternatively you could search for `^http:\/\/test\.domain.*\K` and replace by `yourText`. Btw, I think the start string ancor is a must when OP mentioned *"search for the line beginning with...."*

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^https?://test\.domain.*$\K`
- Replace with: `text_to_add`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                       # beginning of line
    https?              # http  OR https
    ://test\.domain     # literally
    .*                  # 0 or more any character but newline
$                       # end of line
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]